# Does H2O Driverless AI has inbuilt support for sharing a visualization graph from one account to another without downloading?

Tags: graph, visualization, share, h2o, driverless-ai

In H2O Driverless AI, there is a feature in which after we upload a dataset, we can see visualization of the dataset in various plots. So is there a way I can share this graph to a different person in H2O Driverless AI, so that he/she can see the graph dynamically.

Please note that : I dont want to download the graphs, because if I do that, the graph will become static.

What I want is to share the graph to a different person so that he can view the live graph without giving my account credentials.

Is there any way to do this in H2O Driverless AI ?

Answer (score 0):

Each user/account is separate so the dynamic graphs won't be shared. However, you could create a notebook and share that usugin the Python client to build the visualizations. Check out this [example](https://github.com/h2oai/driverlessai-tutorials/blob/master/autoviz/autoviz_client_example.ipynb) which uses Autoviz and Python client.

Comment: but still we need to provide username and password right ? in the doc its mentioned 
cli = Client(address=address, username=username, password=password) 
which requires credentials to initialize a client.

Comment: Yes, the user will need to log in as the licensed user for that instance